# Add differences into table

Tags: sqlite

Using this code

```
SELECT p.recnum
FROM   "project list" p
       left join week01 w
              ON p.recnum = w.recnum
WHERE  w.recnum IS NULL
```

I get a list of all RecNum that exist in "Project List" but not in "Week01". Is there a way to then add all of those RecNum into Week01.RecNum as well as set Week01.UserName to "JustMe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 insert into Week01 (UserName, RecNum)
 select 'JustMe', p.RecNum
 from `Project List` p
 left join Week01 w on p.RecNum = w.RecNum
 where w.RecNum is NULL
```

Comment: Well, that works when Week01 is empty. But I have RecNum's that match with a different username. I'll try to see if "and" will work. Yep! The "and" worked out great! Thank you Juergen.